# Excel Rows Format new value per values of another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I currently have a spreadsheet which has a table with hundreds of reference codes (each reference code has its own row).

I am trying to get each reference to display like so:
REF01|REF02|REF03

The reason I am trying to get the above is the internal system we use recognises the | statement and will return all the references, otherwise I would have to put each reference in one by one which would take a very long time.

I am not sure which function might be used to obtain the above and would appreciate any help I could get :)

I have Microsoft Excel 2010.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique that I have used before.  I will assume that your data is in column `A`, and column `B` is empty.  So, In cell `B1`, use the formula `=A1`.  In cell `B2`, use the formula `=B1 & "|" & A2`.  Then copy this formula down to the end of column `B`.  This will give you a table that will look like

```
REF01    REF01
REF02    REF01|REF02
REF03    REF01|REF02|REF03
...
```

The last cell in column `B` will have the data formatted as you want it to load into your internal system.

Comment: It worked! you sir are an excel genius, thank you for your help! :D